# Condition for true periodicity

Tags: oscillators, vibrations

In *Vibrations and Waves*, French writes that

> The condition for any sort of true periodicity in the combined motion is that the period of the component motions be commensurable- i.e., there exist two integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $$T=n_1T_1=n_2T_2$$

But what is the justification for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should put sufficient details in the question that someone can understand the context without actually going to the book in question.

Here we have a combined signal such that $$x=x_1+x_2$$ where $$x_1=A_1 \cos(\omega_1 t)$$  $$x_2=A_2 \cos(\omega_2 t)$$ so $x_1$ and $x_2$ are periodic with periods $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively. This implies that $$x_1(t+n T_1)=x_1(t)$$  $$x_2(t+nT_2)=x_2(t)$$ for all integers $n$. Also, if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are integers then $n_1 n$ and $n_2 n$ are also integers. So if $x$ is periodic then $$x(t+nT)=x(t)$$  $$x_1(t+nT)+x_2(t+nT)=x_1(t)+x_2(t)$$  $$x_1(t+nT)+x_2(t+nT)=x_1(t+n_1 n T_1)+x_2(t+n_2 n T_2)$$ so we have $$nT=n_1nT_1$$ and $$nT=n_2 n T_2$$ and thus $$T=n_1 T_1 = n_2 T_2$$

Comment: Thanks for the help and ill keep in mind your remarks when posting in the future. Also, I believe you made a typo in the third last equation.

Comment: Oops, yes. I have fixed it